# About heroes and chance packs in BLR

Tags: blacklight-retribution

I've recently started playing **Blacklight: Retribution**, and I like it *(a lot)*, so I want to sink some money into it.

My questions stand as follows:

**1)** If I buy a hero, I still have my default avatar if I wish to play with it ?

**2)** If I buy a hero, his / her weapon unlocks apply only to him / her or others as well. Are their loadouts even modifiable ?

**3)**  **Chance packs**, are they fair ? All items have an equal chance of dropping, or do some items have a lower chance ? are they worth it ?

**4)** Is trading possible and if so, is there a decent marketplace ? If I get *two* of the same skin in a chance pack, can I exchange it ? restrictions ?

**P.S.** Any number of answers is acceptable, If no one is able to answer all, I'll simply post a reward for *the others*, but accept the best answer here also.

Comment: You should split this into multiple questions to fit the format of the site.

Answer (score 1):

I can only fully answer 1, 2, and 4, as I have little experience with question 3.

1. Yes, you can switch between your custom avatar and unlocked heroes in the Hero section of the Customization screen. As this is a *customization* option and not a *loadout* option, you cannot switch while in-game.
2. Heroes' loadouts are not modifiable. You cannot use their equipment or weapons on your custom avatar, nor can you give them your purchased weapons or equipment. You can, however, pick up weapons on the ground while in-game.
3. I don't know if all items in the chance pack have an equal chance of appearing, though from the way they are presented, it seems like a fair bet that it is.
4. "Trading" can be done by attaching items to mail. There are a couple of restrictions: You can only send inactive items (you have to select "Activate later" on the purchase screen), and there is a Zen cost to send items. The Mini Mart section of the Customization screen has a Merchant item which removes the Zen cost for trading, albeit temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

Items in chance packs have different probabilities of dropping, with the main item having the lowest probability, according to player research:

http://blacklight-wiki.perfectworld.com/index.php/Chance_Packs